# GeoIP in Matomo, previous Piwik map Tokyo wards

Tags: geoip, matomo, geoip2, geolite2, geolitecity

According to https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/release-notes/

> Effective July 24th, we will be mapping more IP addresses to special
>   wards of Tokyo instead of Tokyo itself.

Matomo that I use has enabled GeoIP2 plugin and I have downloaded the free database https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/ into `misc` folder.

As the Geolocation setting now allow to enable this:

[image]

Which seems auto-detecting the GeoLite2 binary files under `misc` folder.

I have written some PHP code to test the GeoLite2 binary file and it seems being able to detect Tokyo ward. For example, I can detect IP address `113.35.99.200`

```
[city] => Array
    (
        [geoname_id] => 1852140
        [names] => Array
            (
                [en] => Shinagawa
                [ja] => 品川区
            )

    )
```

So the ward seems detected fine.

But from the dashboard where the map is displaying, the visits are still Tokyo. There is all 'undefined' regions in Japan. Switching to Cities, there is only one city "Tokyo".

[image]

What happens to other cities or other wards? How can I see them in visitor map?

Comment: Hi, I have to double-check but I am pretty sure this is the same issue as I answered here: https://forum.matomo.org/t/showing-map-of-visits-by-region-doesnt-work/31061/2?u=lukas

Matomo has upgraded to GeoIP2 and ISO regions but the map hasn't yet which breaks in some cases where the location code have changed when migrating from FIPS codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is most likely the issue, is that  Matomo has upgraded to GeoIP2 and ISO regions in one of the last releases but the map hasn't yet and still uses the old FIPS codes that differ in some regions, which breaks the map in these cases.

You can find out more about this issue here:

https://forum.matomo.org/t/showing-map-of-visits-by-region-doesnt-work/31061

https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo/issues/13691

There is ongoing work to completely replace the map with a modern component which would fix this issue, but this will take some time:
https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo/issues/11929